# OSX Sierra Xcode clang libc++ missing qualifier bug

Tags: xcode, macos, c++11, clang, libc++

Using:

```
Apple LLVM version 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.42.1)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin16.1.0
```

there are huge numbers of errors introduced in the standard library by a really stupid coding error: an example is here:

```
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/chrono:281:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/ratio:256:81: fatal error:
     unknown class name 'false_type'; did you mean '::std::false_type'?
template                     struct __is_ratio                     : false_type {};
                                                                               ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/type_traits:278:38: note:
     '::std::false_type' declared here
typedef _LIBCPP_BOOL_CONSTANT(false) false_type;
                                    ^
```

The compiler diagnostic is correct, it should read ::std::false_type. I fixed that but then found the same error is repeated over and over again all over the library. The library worked until I decided to use chrono. The bug, however, is not just in chrono.

Does anyone know if this has been fixed?

Comment: This is almost certainly not a libc++ bug. If I had to guess you're including `<chrono>` inside an already open namespace.

Comment: @EricWF: yep, thanks. sorry for post.